# Paste data from a textbox from one useform to another useform with an empty textbox automatically

Tags: excel, vba, performance

Currently I have a robust macro, in which I calculate some dates determined by a few weeks already established and paste them into some textbox, according to their corresponding one, create an additional button so that these dates are pasted in a timeline in another use form but when calling the first field with the first date and paste it in the "x" field it does not automatically paste, it does not appear in the other useform, in the field that is also a textbox

I ask for help please, by skype or team viewer

psd: attached code, of what I call the field to paste it in the textbox of the other useform.

thanks in advance

```
Private Sub txtDocumentArrival_Change()
```

frmLineTime.txtDocumentArrival = txtfechaLlegadaDocumentos
frmLineTime.txtDocumentArrival = frmDetalles.txtfechaLlegadaDocumentos

End Sub

this is the code

Comment: Dont use screenshots of your code, add the code as text instead.

Comment: It is done, you can help me ?